# --parallel=N not delivering required results

Tags: unix, parallel-processing

I've been working on comparing a sample data generation script using normal & parallel run. I'm using the GNU library 'parallel' for running the script in parallel. The script generates random records in a fixed columns of 100 & varying row size. Below is my snippet that generates random records:

```
for i in $(seq $rows)
do
tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c 2000 > tmp
gawk '$1=$1' FIELDWIDTHS='I put here the varying column lengths' OFS=, tmp >> tmp1
done
```

Here are the stats I've collected:

```
"# of Rows" "# of columns"  "Time took(sec)"    "Time took, using & (sec)"  "Time took Parallelism=4(sec)"
100     100 1   1   ~0
1000    100 6   5   5
10000   100 51  59  51
100000  100 895 576 543
1000000 100 10462   11765   11468
```

Even if I introduce parallel processing using the 'parallel' utility, I don't see any change in elapsed time compared to what I get in normal processing. Any ideas, insights, help would be appreciated.

My CPU has 4 cores and I want to make sure the program utilizes all the cores while executing.

Thanks,
Adil

Comment: You may like to identify where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Maxim,
Since I'm not using any manual procedure to introduce parallelism in the script, the bottleneck identification itself is a bottleneck. However, I could see the mstat while the script executes that all the cores are utilized at some or the other instant of time but the major part of %idle time remains higher (<80%) almost all the time.
Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: I would look into how reading from `/dev/urandom` scales.

Answer (score 0):

@Maxim has a good point. Try:

```
cat /dev/urandom | pv > /dev/null
```

Does that give data fast enough? If not try installing `haveged`.

`/dev/urandom` gives you 8-bit of random data, but you only keep the 62 values, so you will be throwing away a lot of values. If `/dev/urandom` is the bottleneck, then an improvement would be to use the full value of the random data. If you MIME-encode the random value, you will be using all bytes, and get 6-bit values (= 64 different values).

Comment: The advantage of `urandom` is that it doesn't block when it's low on entropy. This is a downside as well, because it means your random number quality is worse. If you're bothered about random quality, then you should simply never do this, and if you're not... almost any RNG will be fine anyway ;)

Comment: The data generation rate is ~11MB/s with /dev/urandom. That's fast. Haven't used MIME yet, will try. But back to the issue, I still don't get the slow performance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake, and you are going to say *DOH!*

You write to > tmp. So if you run multiple jobs in parallel, you will be overwriting this file again and again. The solution is to skip the tmpfile. This way you can match the speed of /dev/urandom, which then becomes the bottleneck:

```
orig() {
  rows=$1
  for i in $(seq $rows)
  do
  tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c 2000 > tmp
  gawk '$1=$1' FIELDWIDTHS="$(seq 100|xargs)" OFS=, tmp >> tmp1
  done
}

rm tmp1
# Around 200 KB/s
(orig 1000; cat tmp1) | pv | wc -c

pipeversion() {
  rows=$1
  base64 -w 2000 < /dev/urandom | head -n $rows |
    gawk '$1=$1' FIELDWIDTHS="$(seq 100|xargs)" OFS=,;
}

# Around 12 MB/s
pipeversion 1000 | pv | wc -c

export -f pipeversion

# Around 12 MB/s - because /dev/urandom is the bottleneck
seq 100 | parallel pipeversion 1000 | pv | wc -c
```